# Add resource folder to export

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I am using Eclipse to code my java project and have a folder called res which holds any images or text files that are needed for the project to work properly. When run in the ide, the source folder can reference the res folder with no problem, but when i export it to my desktop, the res folder isn't exported along with the source folder. I have to create a folder on my desktop holding the exported jar and then recreate the res folder within that folder in order for it to work. I've looked around but can't get a working answer on how to get the res folder to export with the jar file. I've tried making the res folder a source folder but that didn't work. Thanks for your time!

Comment: How do you attempt to access files located in your res folder in your code?

Comment: For an image I'd write `res/(Image name)` as the location. Similar for a text file as well.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the problem that the res folder is getting exported but you're not accessing the files in the correct way. When you access files in your res folder, you have to do it in a different way to make it continue to work after you create a jar file.

```
this.getClass().getResource("/res/fileNameToAccess");
```

The first "/" refers to the base folder of your jar file.

If it's the case that the files aren't getting placed into the jar file at all, I am unsure. It should get exported after you add it as a source folder.

Comment: I think I'm confused on how to use this in my code. This would be how I create an image in my program: `private Image dirt = new ImageIcon("res/Dirt.png").getImage();` How do you suggest I use your code?

Comment: @yanman1234 I believe in that case it would be done like this: `Image dirt = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/res/Dirt.png"));` But for more help you should take a look at getResource(). It's what you need to get it working.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work. I'll take a look into getResource() though.

Comment: @yanman1234 My only other idea is maybe your res folder isn't in the root directory of your project. If that's not the problem, I found this thread which gives a few good examples http://www.coderanch.com/t/552720/java/java/access-text-file-JAR

Comment: I think this may help explain what I'm trying to do [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE7ezYCTPe4) The applicable part is from 2:30 to 3:25. I of course tried following what he said but it failed to work.